# Where should one store users' text on a DB-driven site?

Tags: database, postgresql, text, storage

This seems like a super obvious question, but I can't find a good answer anywhere.

Where should I store my users' text? My site lets users write posts of arbitrary length that needs to be stored somewhere.

Should this be in the DB? What do I do about text limits?

Or should it be in files referenced by the DB? Are there any serious pitfalls to look out for?

Comment: Python/Django/PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to store it in your Database, if you want to limit the text that is inserted you can use the maxlength Attribute in the input field that your customers are using to submit their comments.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp
Another good approach is to use some social plugin and allow your customers to post comments using their facebook or twitter accounts:
Some references:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/
http://disqus.com/

Comment: Your links text are all "enter link description here" D:

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to rely on the maxlength attribute.  Whether you use get or post, it's very easy to manipulate the data being posted back to the server.  maxlength is good for user friendliness though.

Comment: You are right, but this is a start, it's easy to handle the length of the string that is used though the script that it is used

Comment: I like this solution.

This isn't for a commenting feature per se. It's for all text based content on the site. They really need to be arbitrary length though (some content is tens of thousands of words).

Does it make sense to chain blocks? Say each block is 5000 chars, and has a ref to the 'next' block in that text?

Comment: Update: maximum size for a field in Postgres is 1GB, so no real problem here

Answer (score 0):

I would just put it in the database, and set a limit of, say 5000 characters.  Or however long would suit you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+ then I would use varchar(MAX).  This will store up to 2GB of data, but only use what is required of the longest contents in the column.  If not SQL Server 2005+, then I would use varchar(8000) or there is a text datatype in both MySql and SQL Server.  I would stay away from the text datatype if the field needs to be searchable though.